# Phonegap Sencha app Google maps API not loading when wifi is disabled on iphone

Tags: api, google-maps, cordova, sencha-touch-2

Looking for help as I'm stumped on this. I'm using a sencha map wrapped in phonegap for iphone. The map loads perfectly when wifi is enabled but when it is turned off the map does not display and informs me that 'Google Maps API is required'. The script I'm using in my index.html file in the www directory is the one suggested by sencha...

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

As I mentioned when I enable wifi the script loads and the map displays. I have also wrapped my app for android devices and the script loads here both when wifi is disabled and enabled.

Would love to hear some suggestions on how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complicated issue, but can be done. Here is a link to someone who has solved this:

http://rohdef.dk/wp3/?p=151

Sencha should really update their code to allow their google maps views to fail gracefully instead of freezing the whole app. To make things worse, even restarting the app later when there is connection doesn't help because of caching, you have to re-install from apple store.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your link seems to be exactly what I was looking for at the time of posting. Due to time constraints at the time of development I didn't come across anything like your answer and ended up replacing Google Maps with the Leaflet Javascript Library http://leafletjs.com/ . It catered for all the functionality I required for the app and worked flawlessly. Thanks for your reply again though.